# How can I display months without no data?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I follow the following blog http://sqljason.com/2018/03/display-last-n-months-selected-month-using-single-date-dimension-in-powe... in order to display Display Last N Months & Selected Month using Single Date Dimension in Power BI.

I've an issue when trying to display month-year when there is no data in the fact table sales.

I did modification: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amd7BXzYs7AVg3xJ1MKPYI_PIw3z

How to show to show for example October, november and december 2015  as an example?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your PBIX file and looked through it.
I am unsure what you exactly want to see, because your report has a few quirks in it.

I'll try to sum them up:

- You have a 'select month' drop down menu ánd a slider for selecting the number of months (As 'sales for last x months). This doesn't work. Since you now need to manually select the wanted months in the drop down menu with CTRL+Click (On each month) ánd you need to use the slider.
- Next to that, your calculations seem to be wrong. If I only select Dec-16 I get 70. If I select Nov-16 and Dec-16, the sales in Dec-16 suddenly become 70 and Nov-16 takes over. If I select until July-16, July-16 gets 70 and Dec-16 gets 120.. I don't know if this is how you want it but it looks like strange behaviour.
- A good tip for measures. If you sum, divide or do any calculation. End with +0. That way you wont see (Blank) but 0. E.g.

```
Sales (Selected Month) = SUM(Sales[Sales]) + 0
```

- Also, you have made a small date table, which is good. But you don't use this consistently through your report. For selecting months you use the date table and for the graph you use the date in the sales table. It is better to use the date table for dates, since that is it's sole purpose.